# VBS - не запускается explorer.exe

Tags: windows, vbscript, explorer

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe",0
objShell.Run "explorer.exe"
```

Хочу перезапустить процесс `explorer.exe`, процесс завершается, но снова не запускается, что я делаю не так? Пробовал прописывать и без `.exe`, и вот так: `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`, но безрезультатно.